# Angularjs How to run functions in order?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a form with ng-submit with 2 functions func1 & func2. I want to run the func1 first and then func2 later.

My code looks like the following

```
$scope.funct1= function(){  };
$scope.funct2= function(){  };
```

Comment: "later" when? On subsequent calls or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your functions is not `promise` function.

Just need call two functions from View:

```
<form ng-submit="func1(); func2()">
  // something
</form>
```

If your `func1()` is promise function, call function 2 (inside function 1) when finished function 1:

```
$scope.func1 = function () {

  // After finished this function, call function 2
  $scope.func2();
};
```

Comment: Now func2() will execute 2 times.

Answer (score 2):

call func2 inside func1

```
$scope.funct1= function(){
    alert("func 1");
    $scope.funct2();

}

 $scope.funct2= function(){ 
   alert("func 2")
}
```